# Eclipse plugin develop configurations

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, configuration-files

I am trying to develop an eclipse plugin and my orientor wants me to create a configuration file for the plugin.
She said all i need to put in this configuration file is a little variable and boolean value which i will need to get later: 'showPluginDestroyJavadoc=true'

I have already tried to search google for it, but you all know that plugin development don´t have a lot of info on web. Especially about configuration files

Question is: How do i create a configuration file for my eclipse plugin? I want the plugin to be able to read configuration file before the user does anything using my plugin. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why a configuration file? Eclipse plugins are usually configured through the Eclipse preferences. A tutorial regarding how to add preference functionality to a plugin can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePreferences/article.html).

If your orientor absolutely want you to define the settings by a file, you can still use preferences and set the values throught a plugincustomization file, more info [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/08/07/eclipse-papercut-9-default-preference-settings-via-plugin_customization-ini-type-filter-example/)